# Git Repository Folder Upload Structure

Tags: git, laravel

I have some error in my GIT setup, I cannot figure out. When I push my blank laravel project to my git repo on bitbucket, it does not only upload the project itself, but the folder containing the project.

[image]

But I only want the folder MFS to be the one, whos content will be uploaded. I setup my git repository WITHIN the MFS folder, so I expected that should work. Why is the encompassing folder uploaded too?

Within the MFS folder I executed:

- git remote add origin PATHTOGIT
- git push -u origin master

Comment: did you run `git init` inside Sites directory?

Comment: how can I check if it has been init within Sites?

Comment: run `ls -al` to check if a .git directory exists

Comment: no .git directory there

Comment: In which directory did you run the command?

Comment: I just ran it within the MFS folder

Comment: And when I now try to push, I get `error: src refspec master does not match any.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems your project is initialized in the wrong directory. Take backup of files in case something goes wrong

```
#run from Sites directory
#deletes branch from remote
git push -d origin master

#run from Sites directory
rm -rf .git

#run from MFS directory
git init
git add .
git commit -m 'message'
git remote add origin PATHTOGIT
git push -u origin master
```